# How do I know if the user selected the "hide my email" option when logging in to Apple?

Tags: swift

If the user has selected the option "hide my email". I need to handle a logic I wrote. How do you know in the background that the user has selected this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not have unique logic with it. If the user chooses "hide my email" Apple will create an email as "hdsgfdsc@privaterelay.appleid.com" to communicate with you and the user. All emails you will send to that email will be redirected to the user's own email, which he hides from you.

if you still need special logic, you can add a String check after the @. If there will be privaterelay.appleid.com then implement your special logic.

```
func getMainPart(s: String) -> String {
    var v = s.componentsSeparatedByString("@").last?.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    v?.removeLast()

    return (v!.last)!
}
```

```
let email1 = "hdsgfdsc@privaterelay.appleid.com"
let s = getMainPart(email1)
print(s) // this outputs: privaterelay
```

So you will know that your email domain is `privaterelay` and implement your logic after `if` statement.

Comment: This is an wrong answer for the question. Apple creates email addresses with `@privaterelay.appleid.com` for "Sign in with Apple" which is different from iCloud+ Hide My Email feature. The latter produces `@icloud.com` email addresses